Push notifications: switch from GCM `DeprecatedApi` to FCM `Requested entity was not found.`
I have a weird behavior since I made the move from Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) to Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) for all my Android users.
I didn't change anything on the app side - google-services.json is still the same. And no update has been sent.
The changes I made are only backend. May I share them here with you because my project is open-source.
My situation before: code is here

node-pushnotifications v2, using gcm field

When trying to send a push notif, it's returning the error message DeprecatedApi
I did some changes on my Node's server: code is here

node-pushnotifications from v2 to v3
added the service-account firebase file, well parsed

and here is the weird thing:
on an already installed app, it's now returning Requested entity was not found.
on a newly installed app, WITHOUT ANY CODE CHANGE on the app side, the notification is properly sent.
What can I do ?

I was facing the same issue. I updated the version node-pushnotifications as well from v2 to v3.
You wrote: "on a newly installed app, WITHOUT ANY CODE CHANGE on the app side, the notification is properly sent.".
That's because the error Requested entity was not found. is similar to the error NotRegistered we had to handle before. It means that the token is no longer valid and we should delete it from the database.
